# Stored procedure in class and global variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, class, stored-procedures

I have a class called UserInfo. Within this class I call a SQL stored procedure to validate the user. The stored procedure returns an output.

I get the output and store it in the local variable in the class which in this case is only accessible within UserInfo class.

Here's the class:

```
public class UserInfo
{
    public void validateUser(string username, string password)
    {
        string constring = "Data Source=db;Initial Catalog=Portal;User ID=u;Password=p";

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("agentAuthentication", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@loginresults", SqlDbType.BigInt, 8);
                cmd.Parameters["@loginresults"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();

                int result =Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@loginresults"].Value);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

On the button click of the login page I call this class to validate the user.

```
 protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string username = text1.Value.Trim();
            string password = text2.Value.Trim();

            UserInfo u = new UserInfo();
            u.validateUser(username, password);

            int result = 0;

            if (result == 0)
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Incorrect username or password');</script>");
            }

            if (result == 2)
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Your account is inactive');</script>");
            }

            if (result != 0 && result != 2)
            {
                Session["isLoggedIn"] = 1;
                Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.ToString();
        }
    }
```

How can I store the returned value from the stored procedure so I can access it in the code behind of the button click?

As you can see the result is declared in two places. I want to declare the **result** in the class and check the value on the button click event.

The stored procedure return three types of output:

1. Returns 0 if username or password is incorrect
2. Returns 2 if account is inactive
3. Else it return the ID of the user.

Comment: Make the return type of the function validateUser() as int. assign that to result in page load

Comment: Get rid of that try/catch block. It will be hiding exceptions from you. Based on your code, I think you really need to see what exceptions are being thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `UserInfo` class change `public void validateUser(string username, string password)` 
to `public int validateUser(string username, string password)` and return the result. declare this result variable outside of `using` clause and set its initial value to 0.

In the `btnLogin_Click` change `u.validateUser(username, password);` to `int result = u.validateUser(username, password);` and you are done.

Comment: Thank you. I knew it would be something simple.